# htaccess .php rewrite not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite a url such as:

www.domain.com/file/name.php?id=1

to without the .php like this:

www.domain.com/file/name?id=1

I have tried altering the htaccess that's placed in the file directory to:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

But it just doesn't work and every time I've tried typing in www.domain.com/file/name?id=1 I get a 404 error.

I've tried all the answers on here relating to this to make sure its not a duplicated question and also double checked to make sure mod rewrite is enabled but I'm at a complete loss now!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Whats the output of `RewriteLog` and `ErrorLog`?

Comment: a lot of undefined variables pointing to my header and footer includes

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `RewriteRule ^name$ name.php`

This is from my own .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^name$ name.php

</IfModule>
```